# How to hide rows based on multiple drop downs in Excel?

Tags: excel, vba, drop-down-menu, show-hide

I have seen similar versions of this question asked, but I cannot find code that works. I have a sheet where I need to hide rows based on certain drop down values. This is the code I have but it is not working:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

  If Intersect(Target, Range("A1,A5")) Is Nothing Or Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then
      Exit Sub
      
        ElseIf Range("A1").Value = "November" And Range("A5").Value = "Actual" Then
        
            Rows("15:33").EntireRow.Hidden = False
            Rows("34:70").EntireRow.Hidden = True
            Rows("71:150").EntireRow.Hidden = True
      
    
        ElseIf Range("A1").Value = "November" And Range("A5").Value <> "Actual" Then
        
            Rows("15:33").EntireRow.Hidden = True
            Rows("34:70").EntireRow.Hidden = False
            Rows("71:150").EntireRow.Hidden = True
    
        ElseIf Range("A1").Value = "December" And Range("A5").Value <> "Actual" Then
        
            Rows("15:70").EntireRow.Hidden = True
            Rows("71:107").EntireRow.Hidden = False
            Rows("108:150").EntireRow.Hidden = True
    
        ElseIf Range("A1").Value = "December" And Range("A5").Value = "Actual" Then
        
            Rows("15:91").EntireRow.Hidden = True
            Rows("92:107").EntireRow.Hidden = False
            Rows("108:150").EntireRow.Hidden = True
        
        ElseIf Range("A1").Value = "October" Then
        
            Rows("15:107").EntireRow.Hidden = True
            Rows("108:123").EntireRow.Hidden = False
            Rows("124:150").EntireRow.Hidden = True
    
        ElseIf Range("A1").Value = "September" Then
    
            Rows("15:123").EntireRow.Hidden = True
            Rows("124:150").EntireRow.Hidden = False
    
    End If
    
    
End Sub
```

Comment: please [edit] the post to include a description of what it is doing/not doing that is incorrect.  Please note any errors you get and on which line.  "Not Working" does not give enough information to help us help you.  Please see: [mcve] and [ask]

Comment: BTW, and this may be what is intended but `Range("A1,A5")` only looks at `A1` AND `A5` not `A1` THROUGH `A5`  for that you want `Range("A1:A5")`

Comment: You have duplicated `ElseIf` clauses with the same content ?